# An aspx page is called sometime and some time not

Tags: asp.net

I am using a `generateimage.aspx` page which is used as an image source for an image.
When this page is called I am passing a querystring and then using a `Session["abc"]` var whose value is being returned as a jpg image.

The page is called as

```
Context.Items["display"]="img src=" + Context.Items["Ch_BaseSvr"] + 
    "GenerateImage.aspx?text=P"
```

Now the problem is that sometimes this page is called and sometimes not.
Thus, when the page is not called the image value that is being returned is that which is assigned to the var in previous Session.

Please let me know what might be the reason that the page is called sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: I don't know why you are experiencing this problem, but it's more appropriate to use an ashx than aspx for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it may be cached. Try setting

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

on your generateimage.aspx page.